# WPF Close all child window except active child window and main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have C# WinForms code as follows to close all child forms when I open a new child form:

```
private void CloseAllActiveForms(Form[] MdiChildren)
{
    Form[] childArray = MdiChildren;
    foreach (Form childform in childArray)
    {
        childform.Close();
    }
}
```

How can I use in WPF windows?

I tried the below code, but it will close all windows including the Parent and the Active window.

```
private void CloseAllWindows()
{
    for (int intCounter = App.Current.Windows.Count - 1; intCounter >= 0; intCounter--)
    {
        Application.Current.Windows[intCounter].Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, MDI support for WPF is limited, so try using the Tag attribute when you create your pseudo-child windows:

```
Window child = new Window();
child.Tag = "mdi_child";
```

Then, in your loop, modify it like this:

```
foreach (Window win in App.Current.Windows)
{
    if (!win.IsFocused && win.Tag.ToString() == "mdi_child")
    {
        win.Close();
    }
}
```

Note that for the above solution to work, ALL windows must have a Tag attribute, or else an Exception will be thrown at `win.Tag.ToString()`.

Comment: Is there alternative beside using MDI?

Comment: MDI-style applications have "gone out of style," so that is kind of the reason why WPF dropped support. What is the goal of your application?

Comment: The most common alternative to MDI-based applications is a tabbed-based interface. The child windows become tabs, and all the tabs exist in the same window. Sorry, the previous comment hardly answers your questions.

Comment: I am having a wpf app with menu... I need to click on the menus to show another window within the main window... When I click on another menu item, the previous window that is opened should be closed before displaying the new window.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to stick to MDI. Tabbed interface would not make as much sense. A complete explanation of how to do MDI is long, but here is a good project that extends WPF:
http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

Comment: If I answered your question, upvote it or accept it if you don't mind :)

Comment: HI John, this library is great, though it is not exactly what I required. But it does helps... Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a method I use in WPF to close all child windows of my program, this code goes in the main `window.cs` file, but you could modify `if(item!=this)` to check for a particular window:

```
foreach(Window item in App.Current.Windows)
{
    if(item!=this)
        item.Close();
}
```

No faffing around with sub-classes or more lists (especially as the code already has a list of windows associated with it.)

If you wanted to selectively close windows then you could always modify the if statement to use a variable on the window class or check one of the pre-existing variables *(such as a the class of the parent window)* on the base window class.